# Send message to multiple facebook friends using Android facebook API

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an application in which user can share messages with his/her Facebook friends. I am using Facebook API for android. I am able to authenticate user, as well as get my friend list as a Facebook user and also post message on wall, but I am looking for sending message/post on wall to my friends and I didn't get any solution for that, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/